# How to use 2d array with form in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, forms, multidimensional-array

I have a model. In that model, I created an array attribute, but I can't use that attribute in form.

This is my problem:

```
= form_for :my_form_name do |f|
  %table
    - for i in 1..10 do
      %tr
        - for j in 1..10 do
          %td
            = f.text_field :example[i][j]
```

In this case, I want to collect data from boxes to attribute called example.

When I run application, I got this error:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you call `[]` on `:example`, instead of creating symbol. Just use string

```
= f.text_field "example[#{i}][#{j}]"
```

Comment: Thanks, I wrote like that but I have new error: ``undefined method `example[1][1]' for #<``

Comment: That's the other thing. `form_for` accepts object, that it extracts values from for defaults in the fields. That's why it called `example[1][1]` on `:my_form_name`. What you need is `form_tag` method. It has different arguments, check docs http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag

Comment: Thank you, and maybe I will edit my model.rb like this: `serialize :example`